# Tomcat - JRE_HOME Environment is not defined properly - Java 11

Tags: java, tomcat, openjdk-11

I am trying to run the project in netbeans 12.2 and using Java 11.

JRE is not available in Java 11

How to run tomcat on java 11

I am getting the below error
**The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program**

Answer (score 0):

> JRE is not available in Java 11

Correct.  JRE distros are not provided by Oracle or from the OpenJDK downloads site since Java 9.

You should download and install a Java 11 JDK instead.  (You could also obtain a JRE installer from a 3rd-party vendor.)

> I am getting the below error The `JRE_HOME` environment variable is not defined correctly This environment variable is needed to run this program

You need to define the `JRE_HOME` environment variable, and set it to the top directory of your JDK installation.

Alternatively, you could define the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and set it to the top directory of your JDK installation.  Apparently `JAVA_HOME` is used as a fallback if `JRE_HOME` is not set.

Note that the Tomcat documentation includes a page on configuration ... that you should read.  The Tomcat 8.5 version is [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/setup.html).

Comment: Thank you, But issue is resolved after removing the existing installation of tomcat and freshly installing it

also in netbeans disabled "Compile on Save" option.

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

issue is resolved after removing the existing installation of tomcat and freshly installing it also in netbeans disabled "Compile on Save" option. Now it is working fine

Comment: A solution that basically says "reinstall it" is not very satisfying.  'Cos it doesn't help anyone understand what was broken in the first place, why it was broken, or whether there is a better fix.  Yes it works for you, but it could be blind alley for other people.

Answer (score 0):

> Please remove the existing JRE_HOME path in the system variables/user
> variable in the environments and add CATALINA_HOME

```
CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59


CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\lib
```

> and re-run the startup.bat/startup.sh file